# How to fix the following SQL Server error instalation on ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, mysql

Hello I am trying to run SQL Server in my computer I have ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 64-bit, I am following these steps: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-ubuntu,

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list
```

Since I have ubuntu 14 running first I performed:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

To avoid the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mssql-server : Depends: openssl (>= 1.0.2) but 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.21 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I took this solution from this site:

http://www.haidongji.com/2016/11/17/initial-impressions-of-sql-server-v-next-public-preview/comment-page-1/#comment-40488

However after it the result was the same, I mean the same error,I would like to appreciate any support to overcome this situation, thanks for the attention,

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     mssql-server : Depends: openssl (>= 1.0.2) but 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.21 is to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 3):

The SQL Server on Linux [Release Notes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes) from 16-Nov-2016 state clearly that the supported platforms are:

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.2 Workstation, Server, and Desktop with Ext4 or XFS filesystems;
- Ubuntu **16.04** LTS with Ext4 filesystem, and
- Docker Engine 1.8+ on Windows, Mac, or Linux.

Ubuntu 14.04 is not supported.

Comment: I know, that is why I am running sudo apt-get dist-upgrade, In my question I included the link of a web site that used this solution however is not working for me that is the main point.